# Do the characters in Line (by Israel Horovitz) ever fully grasp the absurdity of their behavior and situation?

Tags: character-analysis, israel-horovitz, line

In *Line* (a one-act play by Israel Horovitz), the characters constantly jockey for position in a line. All of the characters seem to have a very different idea of what they're even waiting *for*, or why it's so important to be first in line. Why are they so determined to be first in line? What do they think that they're going to achieve? Also, do they ever figure out how different their conceptions of what they're even waiting for?

In short, to what extent (if any) do the characters recognize the absurdity of their situation and behavior?